# Adding Random Numbers On Click in jQuery

Tags: jquery, math

I understand random numbers and adding numbers, but I don't understand how to add a random number to a number currently displayed.  I have a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CsHyW/) that shows what I have now, but I want that button to add another random number with each click to the current number displayed.

EDIT: I should clarify that my jsFiddle is clunky and I would like a more efficient solution for my question.

Comment: Either get or store the number to display and just add the random number to it.

Answer (score 1):

When setting the `randomnumber` div you can use

```
$("#randomnumber").text(($("#randomnumber").text() * 1) + numRand);
```

where `$("#randomnumber").text() * 1` will be `0` when blank or the latest total

Comment: Do remember to use `parseInt()` (with the radix) or `parseFloat()` (just to be sure).

Comment: @DavidThomas that's what the *1 is doing, but I'd prefer the parseXXX approach

Answer (score 1):

Keep the Sum value in a global variable. Add to that everytime when you generate the new random number.

Jsfiddle sample : http://jsfiddle.net/CsHyW/4/

Answer (score 1):

Why such a convoluted example? If I understand correctly this should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/CsHyW/10/

```
var max = 13;
var $wrap = $('#randomnumber');
$('#getit').click(function() {
    var num = +$wrap.text();
    $wrap.text(num + Math.ceil(Math.random() * max));
});
```

Comment: +1 for the plus trick. instead of using parseInt is that right ?

Comment: yup, `+` just converts the string to a number.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to either store all the numbers generated or to add their value into an accumulated variable. Here's a fiddle with both and it will alert the array of numbers as well as the accumulated result.

[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/CsHyW/5/)